# SQL Query + Join

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I have 2 tables - Client, Jobs, 
Client - clientID,clientName,clientCity
Bricklayers - jobNum, clientID, startDate

Now I need to query the database to list me all clients in 3 cities (Charlotte, Raleigh, Wilmington) and if they have a job on the Bricklayers table also list their jobNum(s) and startDate

I'm completely unsure what approach to take to this problem as I've never needed a query like this. I know I need a join and tried an inner join on the clientID in both columns but kept receiving syntax errors.

Comment: can you share what have your tried so far?

Comment: SELECT clientID, clientName, jobNum, startDate
FROM Client,Bricklayers
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.clientID = Bricklayers.clientID 
WHERE clientCity = 'Charlotte' OR 'Raleigh';

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT c.clientID, c.clientName, b.jobNum, b.startDate 
FROM Client c
INNER JOIN Bricklayers b ON c.clientID = b.clientID 
WHERE c.clientCity IN ('Charlotte','Raleigh','Wilmington');
```

Comment: Don't mix syntax.  Use proper `JOIN`.

Comment: I got the same error in my previous attempts (ORA-00918) Column ambiuously defined